# ¿como insertar varios registros a una tabla ? laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Tengo un problema al registrar los valores que obtengo de una api, al buscarlos y mostrarlos en mi vista todo bien, pero al momento de guardarlos en la bd , ,solo el ultimo valor del  array se guarda, los demas valores no los logro  guardar en la bd.
los valores que obtengo  al aplicar un dd son:

```
request: Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\ParameterBag {#44 ▼
    #parameters: array:9 [▼
      "_token" => ""
      "ImportId" => array:8 [▶]
      "ImportLinea" => array:8 [▶]
      "ImportnNumProduc" => array:8 [▶]
      "ImportTipoProduc" => array:8 [▶]
      "ImportPais" => array:8 [▶]
      "ImportETA" => array:8 [▶]
      "ImportRealETA" => array:8 [▶]
      "ImportSucursal" => array:8 [▶]
```

intente de esta manera,

```
 foreach ($request->all() as $req){
dd($request);
 $prueba=  ImportOperCont::create([
 "ImportId" => => $req['ImportId'],
      "ImportLinea" => => $req['ImportLinea'],
      "ImportnNumProduc" => => $req['ImportnNumProduc'],
      "ImportTipoProduc" => => $req['ImportTipoProduc'],
      "ImportPais" => => $req['ImportPais'],
      "ImportETA" => => $req['ImportETA'],
      "ImportRealETA" => => $req['ImportRealETA'],
      "ImportSucursal" => => $req['ImportSucursal']
]);
          // dd($prueba);
        }
```

en el modelo los tengo esos campos en el fillable.

recibo este mensaje de error

```
ErrorException
Illegal string offset
```

al aplicar dd al $req , me muestra solo el valor del "_token"

Comment: por lo que veo te esta devolviendo una matriz, debes hacer el recorrido porque quieres guardar un array como string y no es posible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sucede que la `api` no te está devolviendo un **arreglo de modelos**, sino que te devuelve una **matriz**.
Algo como esto.

```
(Requiest) => {
    [0]=> {
     ["ImportId"]=> { [0]=> 1, [1]=> 2, }.
     ["ImportPais"]=> {[0]=> "Canadá", [1]=> "Holanda" }
    },
    [1]=> {
     ["ImportId"] => { [0]=> 1, [1]=> 2, }
     ["ImportPais"]=> {[0]=> "Marruecos", [1]=> "Argelia" }
    },
    [2]=> {
     ["ImportId"] => { [0]=> 1, [1]=> 2, }
     ["ImportPais"]=> {[0]=> "Japón", [1]=> "Rusia" }
    },
}
```

Para hacer lo que deseas tendrías que anidar un ciclo dentro de tu ciclo `foreach`.

```php
foreach ($request->all() as $req){
    $len = count($req['ImpotId']);
    for ($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++){
        $prueba=  ImportOperCont::create([
            "ImportId" => $req['ImportId'][$i],
            "ImportLinea" => $req['ImportLinea'][$i],
            "ImportnNumProduc" => $req['ImportnNumProduc'][$i],
            "ImportTipoProduc" => $req['ImportTipoProduc'][$i],
            "ImportPais" => $req['ImportPais'][$i],
            "ImportETA" => $req['ImportETA'][$i],
            "ImportRealETA" => $req['ImportRealETA'][$i],
            "ImportSucursal" => $req['ImportSucursal'][$i]
        ]);
    }
}
```

Algo como eso.
El error `offset` te lo marca cuando quieres acceder a un `índice` inexistente en el arreglo. No se como es el código que si te funcionó pero solo te acepta el último valor, pero si es similar al que muestras podrías intenta anidarle un ciclo como en el ejemplo que te puse